# How to select value only in JoinMap with JPA 2.1 CriteriaBuilder?(Eclipselink)

Tags: eclipselink, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I have:

```
private MapJoin<Agent, String, String> idNo1;    
private Root<Agent> agent;

agent = query.from(Agent.class);
idNo1 = agent.joinMap("data");

c.multiselect(agent.get("name"), idNo1.value());
```

RESULT PARSED SQL:

```
select a.name, d.value, d.key from agent a join agentdata d on a.id=d.agentid.
```

I wonder why d.key is selected although I only call value() method. How can I get resolve this situation to get value only without key.

Thanks.